# Ambiguous column in PostgreSQL UPSERT (writeable CTE) using one table to update another

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query, upsert

I have a table called `users_import` into which I am parsing and importing a CSV file. Using that table I want to UPDATE my `users` table if the user already exists, or INSERT if it does not already exist. (This is actually a very simplified example of something much more complicated I'm trying to do.)

I am trying to do something very similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702291/912717

Here are the table definitions and query:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users_import (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

WITH upsert AS (
    UPDATE users AS u
    SET
        name = i.name
    FROM users_import AS i
    WHERE u.id = i.id
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO users (name)
    SELECT id, name 
    FROM users_import
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert WHERE upsert.id = users_import.id);
```

That query gives this error:

```
psql:test.sql:23: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 11:  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert WHERE upsert.id = us...
                                                       ^
```

Why is `id` ambiguous and what is causing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `RETURNING *` in the `WITH upsert...` clause has all columns from `users` and all columns from the joined table `users_import`. So the result has two columns named `id` and two columns named `name`, hence the ambiguity when refering to `upsert.id`.

To avoid that, use `RETURNING u.id` if you don't need the rest of the columns.

Comment: Gah. So simple. Thank you.